# Power Automate flow check if date is not empty and null

Tags: excel, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have excel sheet. Using Power Automate flow I am reading the excel data.
Using create item action adding the record in SharePoint list. It will not work if the date is empty or null

Column A |     Date Col

1      |        1/1/2020

2      | 2/2/2020

3      |

It will gives error for 3rd row due to empty column. In Power Automate flow can we check if date is not empty or null?

Comment: Example Value for Created: 2023-10-30T21:03:39.012Z Desired Output: Oct 30, 2023 4:03 PM ****Issue:**** The format is correct, but the time does not indicate the correct time when texted or emailed. Also the time indicated minutes change as it should but the hour keeps the same value per hour. It does not indicate the right time per time even for my time zone central and it does not when I use UTC time Oct 30, 2023, 9:03 PM. I am not sure what I need to enter in the *expression* to ensure it matches per time zone and advances every hour. - **This is the Suggested Expression that Power Automate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below expression in **Condition** action inside "Apply to each" on excel rows:

```
@equals(empty(items('Apply_to_each')?['DateCol']), bool('True'))
```

**Source**: [Check for empty cells in Excel](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/Check-for-empty-cells-in-Excel/td-p/202544)

---

If you are not able to able to use the advanced mode for conditions, use below:

Left condition: `empty(items('Apply_to_each')?['DateCol'])`

Operator: **is equal to**

Right Condition: `bool('True')`

[image]